# Get Eclipse to recognize the maps api

Tags: java, xml, android

Hi I'm developing an Android app and trying to incorporate maps into one of my sub-activities.  Having followed all of the instructions from Android, my java file will not recognize the "MapActivity" or the import statements to include the needed api.  Here is my XML manifest and my class file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  

    <activity android:name=".CadetCommand"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="RedLight"></activity>
    <activity android:name="PTCalculator"></activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

here is my java file:

```
    package edu.elon.cs.mobile;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LandNav extends MapActivity{

}
```

Any suggestion would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the "Google APIs by Google Inc." as SDK in eclipse, not the "SDK Platform Android".

If you don't have it available, it can be downloaded with the Android SDK and AVD manager (android-sdk/tools/android)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used it myself, but if you have an external jar you probably just need to right-click on it and choose "Add to build path" from within eclipse.